# Animation with ggplotly: points disappearing when grouped by colour and/or shape

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly

I am trying to make a scatterplot which animates over 4 frames. Each frame should contain 2 datapoints, which take different shapes & colours according to their positions. Here is the code:

```
# create dataframe
df <- data.frame(
  id=rep(1:2,4),
  x = c(1,2,1,3,1,2,4,3), 
  y = c(1,2,1,3,4,3,4,2), 
  f = c(1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4),
  col=c('down', 'down','down','up', # reflects the y axis being 1/2 or 3/4
        'up', 'up','up','down'),
  shape=c('left', 'left', 'left', 'right', # reflects the x axis being 1/2 or 3/4
          'left', 'left', 'right', 'right')
)

p <- ggplot(df, aes(x, y, colour=col, shape=shape)) +
    geom_point(aes(frame = f), size=10) 

ggplotly(p) %>% animation_opts(frame=2000, transition=1250)
```

When I run it the first frame has 2 points but then subsequent frames have points missing.  I can see all 8 points correctly if I do either of the following:

- remove the colour/shape grouping
- add a facet_wrap(~id) (but I don't want it over two facets)

I can't understand why in some of the frames a point disappears - please help!

thanks in advance

Update - following the hint from Ray below I have amended the code and now it does what I wanted it to do (I used alpha as I didn't want to show a difference between id=1 and id=2).

```
p <- ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) +
    geom_point(aes(frame = f,colour=col, alpha=factor(id)), size=7) +
    geom_point(aes(frame = f,shape=shape, alpha=factor(id)), size=4, colour='white') + 
    #scale_alpha_discrete(limits=c(.95,1)) +
    scale_alpha_manual(values=c(1,1)) +
    scale_shape_manual(values=c(95,3)) + 
    theme(legend.position="none")
ggplotly(p) %>% animation_opts(frame=1000, transition=850)
```

Comment: try to understand how your variables work over time (i.e. the frame steps you want to plot). For example, if you set `shape = as.factor(id)` you will see continuously your 2 objects. Thus the way you work with colour and shape offsets. That is the reason why you see both objects when you remove the colour and shape. Good luck!

Comment: thanks @Ray that has helped enormously.